# RIP v2 summarisation

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, rip

I am learning ccna, and doing some practice on packet tracer.
I have a simple network with two routers, R0 and R1. They are connected to each other through a serial link (`172.16.56.128/30`). R0 is directly connected to a network (`172.16.53.0/25`).
R1 is directly connected to two networks one on fa0/0 (`172.16.54.0/23`) and one on fa0/1 (172.16.56.0/25). 
I have configured rip v2 on both router using no auto-summary. I added both the networks on R1, while I did not add the network(`172.16.56.0/25`) on R0. 
However, the network `172.16.56.0/25` is in the routing table of r1.

```
 172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 3 masks
R       172.16.53.0/25 [120/1] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:09, Serial0/0/1 ///WHY?
C       172.16.54.0/23 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C       172.16.56.0/25 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
C       172.16.56.128/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/1
```

Can anyone explain me why? shouldn't no auto-summary prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`no auto-summary` can not prevent that.

Because when you using dynamic routing protocol like RIP, it will send the subnet mask of the classful boundary, and not the actual subnet mask. The command no auto summary will turn this feature off in RIP, and send the actual subnet mask.

**Update @lucaConfa**

You see that, because you use `no auto-summary` command. so RIP willl use the real subnet mask  and you have **172.16.53.0/25** in routing table.

If you don't use `no auto-summary` command, you will have **172.16.53.0/24**

Comment: Sorry I do not understand, you are saying that no auto-summary will force rip to use the subnet mask instead of the classful one. Am I correct? If that happens then why I have 172.16.53.0 in the routing table? using the actual subnet mask should keep this network out of rip.

Comment: Ok, but why it is included in the routing table of R1? I did not add 172.16.53.0/25 to rip. It should not be there...

Comment: "I did not add 172.16.53.0/25 to rip" ==> You did this on which router?

Comment: on R0 I did not issued the command `network 172.16.53.0`

Comment: Ah, 172.16.53.0 directly connect to R0, by default, RIP will advertise it.Please show your RIP config.

Comment: router rip
 version 2
 network 172.16.0.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless

Comment: Why is the network 172.16.0.0 there in `my show run`?

Comment: It's strange, try reload router and show config again.

Comment: I still have the same problem... maybe that is the way RIP works..